# Designing a 3-bit counter using T-flipflop

Tags: verilog

```
module tff(t,i,qbprev,q,qb);
input t,i,qbprev;
output q,qb;
wire q,qb,w1;
begin
assign w1=qbprev;
if(w1==1)begin
not n1(i,i);
end
assign q=i;
not n2(qb,i);
end
endmodule

module counter(a,b,c,cin,x0,x1,x2);
input a,b,c,cin;
output x0,x1,x2;
reg a,b,c,x0,x1,x2,temp,q,qb;
always@(posedge cin)
begin
tff t1(.t(1) ,.i(a),.qbprev(1),.q(),.qb());
x0=q;
temp=qb;
tff t2(.t(1) ,.i(b),.qbprev(temp),.q(),.qb());
x1=q;
temp=qb;
tff t3(.t(1) ,.i(c),.qbprev(temp),.q(),.qb());
x2=q;
a=x0;
b=x1;
c=x2;
end
endmodule
```

This is my code in verilog. My inputs are - the initial state - a,b,c  and cin

I get many errors with the first of them being "w1 is not a constant" What doesn this mean?

I also get error "Non-net port a cannot be of mode input"  But I want a to be an input!

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modules are instantiated as pieces of hardware. They are not software calls, and you can not create and destroy hardware on the fly therefore:

```
if(w1==1)begin
  not n1(i,i);
end
```

With that in mind I hope that you can see that unless w1 is a constant parameter, and this is a 'generate if' What your describing does not make sense.

instance n1 is not called or created as required, it must always exist.

Also you have the input and output connected to `i`. `i` represent a physical wire it can not be i and not i. these need to be different names to represent different physical wires.

In your second module you have :

```
input a,b,c,cin;
// ...
reg a,b,c; //...
```

Inputs can not be regs as the warning says, just do not declare them as regs for this.

```
input  a,b,c,cin;
output x0,x1,x2;
reg    x0,x1,x2,temp,q,qb;
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but I still don't get what I can do about w1. I want to use it kind of like a clock.  What about the other error?

Comment: More fundamental to the w1 issue is the way you have used `i` to connect both the input and output of the module, I can not describe a solution to your w1 issue until that is resolved.

Comment: I resolved that using another wire     temp1     , then using an if else part.

Comment: Could you edit the question to update it with those changes so I can use your wire names to describe a solution.